# ruby rails dynamo db tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-dynamodb

Im trying to develop an app that uses the dynamoDB from the AWS as DB. I have been trying for the last 2 days with the dynamoid gem but I am about to throw my computer out by the window.

http://blog.megam.co/archives/201

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

https://github.com/Veraticus/Dynamoid

does anyone knows about a tutorial out there?

I started a new rails app

```
rails new newApp -O
```

added to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'dynamoid'
```

then i did

```
bundle install
```

following this i created two initializes:
dynamoid.rb:

```
    Dynamoid.configure do |config|
      config.adapter = 'aws_sdk' # This adapter establishes a connection to the DynamoDB servers using Amazon's own AWS gem.
      config.namespace = "dev" # To namespace tables created by Dynamoid from other tables you might have.
      config.warn_on_scan = true # Output a warning to the logger when you perform a scan rather than a query on a table.
      config.partitioning = true # Spread writes randomly across the database. See "partitioning" below for more.
      config.partition_size = false#200  # Determine the key space size that writes are randomly spread across.
      config.read_capacity = 1 # Read capacity for your tables
      config.write_capacity = 1 # Write capacity for your tables
    end
```

and aws-sdk.rb:

```
    require "aws"
    AWS.config({
      :access_key_id => '##########',
      :secret_access_key => '#############################',
    })
```

when i do

```
rails s
```

it just does not loads the localhost

Answer (score 0):

The DynamoDB gem has a bug with Rails 4.

1. Post your error you get, when you type **rails s**.
2. Are you using Rails 4 or Rails 3?

Our Rails project uses dynamoid https://github.com/indykish/nilavu and fake_dynamo.

We don't use aws-sdk.rb, but it works with aws.yml

```
development:

bucket: megam
use_ssl: false
access_key_id: <acess_key>
secret_access_key: <secret> 
#dynamo_db_endpoint: localhost
#dynamo_db_port: 4567
#dynamo_db_endpoint: dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com # Set the regional endpoint
```

Comment: Thanks!! unfortunately I'm using rails3.

I just went away with fake_dynamo. Instead i'm developing right straight to aws. Once everything is perfect I will change the namespace to "pro".